# Price of a product is 75 negative in Magento 1.6

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

We have big issue in one of our shops. When we set a product price in Magento to 0, the price of the product becomes -75 as a special price. If we set the price to 100 the price becomes 25 shown as special price. So there is always 75 euro's of the real price.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you have any catalog price rules set up?

Comment: Thanks Christopher, we did not look by the catalog price rules. After deleting that one the problem is fixed!